# Upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream. NGINX, uWSGI, supervisor

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, supervisord

I am trying to deploy django on ubuntu 16.04 on a DO droplet using uWSGI, NGINX and supervisor.

I am successfully running the app with

```
python manage.py runserver [ip]:8000
```

and

```
uwsgi --http-socket :8080 --module saleor.wsgi
```

When I try to run the app with supervisor I am getting:

```
502 Bad Gateway in the browser.
```

In the ngxinx logs I am getting: **upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream**

my nginx conf file:

## saleor_nginx.conf

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream saleor {
    server unix:///etc/uwsgi/saleor.sock; # for a file socket
    #server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name example.com; # IP removed from post on purpose
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 4G;   # adjust to taste

    access_log /webapps/saleor/saleor/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /webapps/saleor/saleor/logs/nginx-error.log;

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /webapps/saleor/saleor/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /webapps/saleor/saleor/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  unix:///etc/uwsgi/saleor.sock;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

my saleor_uwsgi.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
die-on-term = true
http-socket = /etc/uwsgi/saleor.sock
log-format = UWSGI uwsgi "%(method) %(uri) %(proto)" %(status) %(size) %(msecs)ms [PID:%(pid):Worker-%(wid)] [RSS:%(rssM)MB]
master = true
max-requests = 100
memory-report = true
chdir = /webapps/saleor
virtualenv = /webapps
module = saleor.wsgi:application
processes = 4
static-map = /static=/app/static
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
```

my supervisor.conf file

```
[program:saleor]
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopsignal=QUIT
command = /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /webapps/saleor/saleor_uwsgi.ini
stderr_logfile = /webapps/saleor/saleor/logs/supervisor_err.log
stdout_logfile = /webapps/saleor/saleor/logs/uwsgi_out.log
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Why isn't supervisor starting the processes as I am starting them separately?

[EDIT]
Adding the uwsgi log:

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /webapps/saleor/saleor_uwsgi.ini
[uwsgi-static] added mapping for /static => /app/static
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.12-debian (64bit) on [Fri Jan 26 11:50:13 2018] ***
compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 31 August 2017 21:02:04
os: Linux-4.4.0-109-generic #132-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 19:52:39 UTC 2018
nodename: srt
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /
detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
chdir() to /webapps/saleor
your processes number limit is 3913
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
building mime-types dictionary from file /etc/mime.types...552 entry found
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/saleor.sock fd 3
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 363840 bytes (355 KB) for 4 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
```

<strike>!!!!!!!!!!!!!! WARNING !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
no request plugin is loaded, you will not be able to manage requests.
you may need to install the package for your language of choice, or simply load it with --plugin.
!!!!!!!!!!! END OF WARNING !!!!!!!!!!</strike>

```
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 2336)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 2337, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 2338, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 2339, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 2340, cores: 1)
```

Some progress:

I've added the uwsgi-plugin-python and updated the uwsgi settings with 
plugins = python3. The warning is now gone.